# "TAG - diff" in gitweb - is it possible?

Tags: git, tags, diff, gitweb

Suppose I have two versions v0.1 and v0.2. In between, there are about 20 commits. Now if I want to make a kind of code review on the two versions, gitweb only offers me the possibility to make diffs between each commit. I would just like a diff of all commits done in between the two versions . Is that possible? 
On the command line it would look like this:

git diff v0.1 v0.2

However, git will open for each file once my diff viewer (meld) and I have no way to see all the changes at once (in one file).

Maybe someone already encountered the same problem and can tell me what to do there?

Greetings 
limepix

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Gitweb, you can just alter the `commitdiff` URL to add the previous commit in the parameter `hp`

E.g. on my gitweb where 0.6.9_beta2 and 0.6.9_beta3 are tags:

http://gitweb.zfs-fuse.net/?p=sehe;a=commitdiff;h=0.6.9_beta3;hp=0.6.9_beta2

You can specify branches too. As long as you use valid unambiguous local ref names, you're ok

On the CLI, I routinely use

```
git diff v0.1 v0.2 | kompare -o -
```